# Cold Crashing Mead. Need help with details

Tags: wine, mead, process, cold-crash

How long should I cold crash a mead for?
Is it possible to get haze in the mead from being cold crashed too long?

The yeast is 71B, and it is one gallon. I had to take the airlock off to put it in the refrigerator, but I covered it in plastic wrap. I do not believe that it will oxidize while in the fridge.

Will it be clear in about a week?

Comment: How long has it fermented?  When did you first make it?  If still hazy, it might not be done fermenting yet.  Mead often takes a month or longer to complete the fermentation.  Cold temperatures will not completely stop fermentation but just slow it down.

Comment: @dmtaylor It is definitely done fermenting, I have had it fermenting for about 5-6 weeks.

Comment: Okay.  It may take longer than a week to clear.  I often forget about my meads and let them sit for months before bottling, so I'm not exactly sure how quickly it will clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time mead makers don't cold crash.  Just let it sit and it will clear over time. If you want to speed it along look into wine fining agents.

Comment: I am cold crashing it now. It is clearing quite well. Thank you for your response. I will look into fining agents.